# Sprite isnt loading - Three.JS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, sprite

For some reason my sprite doesn't seem to load in `Three.JS`.  Can someone help me fix my code?

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with it... It's probably something simple I've overlooked. The code works fine but the sprite doesn't appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sprite</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/three.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container" style = "text-align: center;width: 100%;">
</div>
<script>

 // this function is executed on each animation frame
  function animate(){
    // render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        animate();
    });
  }


  // renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true }); //antialiasing on! :)
  renderer.setClearColorHex( 0xADD8E6, 1 ); //made the colour for the sky blue
  renderer.setSize(720, 600);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // camera
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 800);
  camera.position.z = 200;
  camera.position.y =160;
  camera.position.x = 30;
      camera.rotation.x = -0.5;


  // scene
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

     //CODE HERE

            var ashTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
        {
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7344/ra2l3kgscpvjflafg.jpg')
        });

        var ashMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ 
        map: ashTexture
        })

        var Ash = new THREE.Sprite( ashMaterial );
        Ash.scale.set( 64, 64, 1.0 );
        Ash.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
        scene.add(Ash);                 

     //CODE ENDS HERE

     // add subtle ambient lighting
  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  // directional lighting
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  // start animation
  animate();


</script>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
<title>Sprite</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/three.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container" style = "text-align: center;width: 100%;">
</div>
<script>

// this function is executed on each animation frame
function animate() {
    // render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        animate();
    });
}


// renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true}); //antialiasing on! :)
renderer.setClearColorHex(0xADD8E6, 1); //made the colour for the sky blue
renderer.setSize(720, 600);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 800);
camera.position.z = 200;
camera.position.y = 160;
camera.position.x = 30;
camera.rotation.x = -0.5;


// scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

//CODE HERE

/*var ashTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
 {
 map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7344/ra2l3kgscpvjflafg.jpg')
 });*/
var ashTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7344/ra2l3kgscpvjflafg.jpg');
var ashMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    map: ashTexture
});
var imageWidth = ashMaterial.map.image.width;
var imageHeight = ashMaterial.map.image.height;
var Ash = new THREE.Sprite(ashMaterial);
Ash.scale.set(2 * imageWidth, 2 * imageHeight, 1.0);
Ash.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(Ash);

//CODE ENDS HERE

// add subtle ambient lighting
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// directional lighting
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

// start animation
animate();


</script>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

small changes in your code..

Comment: check this link.... press run button after the page loaded.... http://jsfiddle.net/56yK9/

Comment: For some reason it doesnt show up in a normal browser? can you explain?

Comment: If you are having additional problems, please make a new post, and ask a specific question. Thank you.